# What does the fragment in android-code mean?

Tags: android, android-fragments

could someone explain what the following code mean ?

What does           **FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager
                    .getBackStackEntryCount() - 1) ;** mean ?

What does the

```
fragmentTransaction
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out, R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out)
                .replace(R.id.mainMainFragmentLayout, newFragment)
                .addToBackStack(newFragment.getClass().getName()).commit() ;
```

mean ?

```
public static void addFragment(Fragment originalFragment, Fragment newFragment) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = originalFragment.getActivity().getFragmentManager() ;

    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {

        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager
                .getBackStackEntryCount() - 1) ;

        if (backEntry != null && backEntry.getName().equals(newFragment.getClass().getName()))
            return ;
    }

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction() ;

    fragmentTransaction
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out, R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out)
            .replace(R.id.mainMainFragmentLayout, newFragment)
            .addToBackStack(newFragment.getClass().getName()).commit() ;
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions() ;
}
```

I have google for fragment , but I still can not understand...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think every thing is well documented in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return the total number of fragments added into the stack.

You can use `getName()` method of `FragmentManager.BackStackEntry` which is introduced in API level 14 and it will return a string which you can check as the string stored in `addTobackStack(str)` method during fragment transaction.

```
 FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager
            .getBackStackEntryCount() - 1) ;

Fragment fragment=getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(backEntry.getName());
```

But to get the Fragment name you first need to add fragment into the stack as below with the specific name.

```
  fragmentTrans.addToBackStack("MyFragment");
```